# Why is my Gradient Layer smaller than the UITextField I am applying it to?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, cagradientlayer

I am trying to give my text fields a gradient background. I am using the following code:

```
import UIKit

extension UITextField {
    func gradientBackground(firstColor: UIColor, secondColor: UIColor){
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}

class gradientTeLabel: UITextField {
    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        self.gradientBackground(firstColor: UIColor(red: 0.90, green: 0.61, blue: 0.00, alpha: 1), secondColor: UIColor(red: 0.70, green: 0.61, blue: 0.70, alpha: 1))
    }
}
```

[image: Actual View]

What I did was to create an extension and a class which I will attach to some UITextFields. The result is the gradient layer is a little bit shorter than the textfield and it kind of starts a few pixels higher inside the texfield instead of covering it all. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move code to `layoutSubviews` , As it contains the right bounds

```
class gradientTeLabel: UITextField {
    var once = true
     override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()
        if once {
              self.gradientBackground(firstColor: UIColor(red: 0.90, green: 0.61, blue: 0.00, alpha: 1), secondColor: UIColor(red: 0.70, green: 0.61, blue: 0.70, alpha: 1))
              once = false 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. I can't give ya a vote 'cause my rep is less than 15. I'd definitely give a thumbs up.Why is this happening anyway?

Comment: Inside `didMoveToWindow ` you don't get the correct bounds of the textfield that you assign to the frame of the gradient try to print them inside both methods and you will notice that , also once because `layoutSubviews ` is called multiple times